# Is it possible to use rustfmt to format just the imports?

Tags: rust, config, code-formatting, rust-cargo, rustfmt

I've been messing around with nightly rustfmt and all its options (so many more than the stable version).

So, just out of curiosity: if I want to use rustfmt **only** to format my imports (the `use` statements), without touching the rest of the code, is it possible?

Comment: I don't have a way to test that right now, but perhaps you can set `disable_all_formatting = true` then individually enable the settings you want.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I just tried with `disable_all_formatting = true` and `reorder_imports = true` but it dutifully does not format anything, not even the imports :/

Comment: If you tag an item with `#[cfg_attr(rustfmt, rustfmt_skip)]`, then it won't be formatted. Unfortunately I think you'd have to do this for *every* item that's not an import, which would be too onerous. More info: https://github.com/rust-lang/rustfmt/issues/1322

Answer (score 2):

I think it is impossible since many configurations don't have a `disable` option.

You can find all configurations [here](https://rust-lang.github.io/rustfmt/?version=v1.4.38)